# what android version supports attribute 'hardwareAccelerated' and 'largeHeap'?

Tags: android, xml, eclipse

`error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'hardwareAccelerated' in package 'android'`

This error happens when eclipse android project build is running.

I'm using

`<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">`

`<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8">` right now,

am I using a wrong sdk version?

Also can I find these kind of android attribute working according to sdk version?

Answer (score 0):

These two attributes, 'hardwareAccelerated' and 'largeHeap' attribute supports above Android 3.0( API 11 ),

and I'm using .

I've cleaned my project, but the project still shows the same error.

Still keep looking for the real answer.